# How do I setup multiple username:password in squid proxy server

Tags: authentication, squid, proxy-server

I am able to assign 1 user with password to my squid proxy server but I need to assign multiple users with different password. How do I do this please?

Answer (score 0):

you should run this command to create another user in squid:

```
htpasswd /etc/squid/passwords [USERNAME]
```